# Send comma delimited CSV through SFTP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sftp

I am collecting registration information on my site and need to figure out how to pass all data stored in the MySQL DB (or just portions of it) as a CSV file through an SFTP so our partners can access the information. The pages are built using PHP.

I literally have no idea how to do this and am hoping somebody has experience doing so.

Thanks ahead of time!

---

### EDIT

I don't necessarily need to store the information first- I am trying to take all the values collected during an enrollment process, parse them as a CSV file, then deliver the CSV file through SFTP somehow.

EDIT #2 - 
Configuration on client side changed and we are now using FTPS gien FTPS Server, TCP Port, username, password, data directory (ftp mode being passive). Any suggestions on how to approach using PHP?

Comment: What part of the process is your question regarding exactly? Creating the CSV? Doing the STFP transaction?

Comment: @Austin - sorry I don't understand the question. Not sure this is the answer but I am taking several field variables, holding them in SESSION (such as name, address, etc) then storing that information in a single row in a MySQL DB. My goal is to have the information which is being stored in our DB ALSO passed in SFTP to the partner.

@ Pekka - I am asking for both.

Comment: It's not important... (deleting my previous comment)  Just note that CSV stands for "comma separated values."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really nice PHP extension to handle SSH/SFTP. See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php).

Comment: @Artefactor - Thanks for the help. I just started learning to program a month ago and the link provided is a bit overwhelming although probably very valuable. I have figured out how to create the CSV file needed and tested mailing the file as an email attachment but due to security reasons I cannot deliver this way. Is there a simple script to send information SFTP (much like a mysql connect) or do I have to install several pieces of code on my actual server as the link indicates?